# comparing values of two data structures

Tags: c, data-structures, comparison

I have two data structures:

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}EVENTS;

EVENTS typeone[20];
EVENTS typetwo[20];
```

These have been filled. typeone has been filled till typeone[5] and typetwo till typetwo[8].

I just want to compare the first six of typeone and typetwo and see if there are equal in all their members.

Is there a way to do `typeone[1] == typetwo[1]` 
Basically comparing all the values inside the datastructure at [1]. 
Is there a short way to do this or would I have to loop through each member and compare separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 typedef struct{
     int a;
     int b;
     int c;
 }EVENTS;

 #pragma pack(1)
     EVENTS typeone[20];
     EVENTS typetwo[20];
 #pragma pack()

 int equal(EVENTS* v1, EVENTS* v2)
 {
      return 0==memcmp(v1, v2, sizeof(*v1));
 }
```

Note `#pragma pack(1)`. It ensures that there are no padding bytes in the structures. This way memcmp will not try to compare padding bytes and the comparison is way faster than a field-by-field method, but while in this case the performance is unlikely to be adversely affected, take:

```
     typedef struct{
         char a;
         long b;
     } somestruct;

 #pragma pack(1)
     somestruct foo;
 #pragma pack()
```

Retrieving `foo.b` will take much more machine code than in case of padded structures, because it will miss word-aligned position where it can be retrieved with a single 32-bit instruction, it will have to be picked out with four byte-reads, and then assembled into the target register from these four pieces. So, take the performance impact into account.

Also, check if your compiler supports `#pragma pack`. Most modern compilers do, but exceptions may still happen.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/compare.html). In a nutshell, no, C does not support struct comparison with the `==` operator (the answer in the FAQ states a few reasons as to why this is hard in the general case). You have to write your own function and compare member by member. As was pointed out, `memcmp()` is **not** a guaranteed way due to *unspecified behavior* when accessing padding bytes.

```
int eventsequal (const EVENTS *const a, const EVENTS *const b)
{
    if (a->a != b->a) return 0;
    if (a->b != b->b) return 0;
    if (a->c != b->c) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

And then your example `typeone[1] == typetwo[1]` becomes

```
if (eventsequal (typeone + 1, typetwo + 1)) {
   /* They're equal. */
}
```

Comment: Methinks the correct term is "unspecified values" for the padding, not "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Thanks, what I meant to write, but didn't, was "due to undefined behavior when accessing padding bytes." I have corrected the text.

Comment: Hmm, accessing padding bytes shouldn't be undefined behaviour, that would contradict "The value may be copied into an object of type `unsigned char [n]` (e.g., by `memcpy`); the resulting set of bytes is called the object representation of the value.", wouldn't it? And no, I meant "When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take **unspecified values**."

Comment: @DanielFischer This refers to the state after copying to an unsigned char array. Padding bytes in a struct are indeterminate (C99 Footnote 262). But I realize that accessing those is merely unspecified behavior (C99 J.1). I have edited the text yet again. You take the credit for being insistent!

Comment: Aha. 6.2.6.1 speaks of "unspecified values" of the padding bytes. Footnote 262 (310 in n1570) says "The contents ... are indeterminate". Now, an _indeterminate value_ is either an _unspecified value_ or a trap representation (3.19.2). "The `memcmp` function compares the first `n` characters", there are no trap representations for `char`, so in this context, both terms coincide.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the problem of padding, you have to compare the fields individually. This doesn't have to be all that horrible:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool EVENTS_equal(const EVENTS *e1, const EVENTS *e2)
{
  return e1->a == e2->a && e1->b == e2->b && e1->c == e2->c;
}
```

then just loop:

```
size_t i;
bool   equal = true;

for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
  if(!EVENTS_equal(typeone + i, typetwo + i))
  {
    equal = 0;
    break;
  }
}
```

it's not that much code really, and of course you could trivially encapsulate the looping in a function that cross-compares the *n*  first slots of two `EVENTS` arrays.